# what is `with check` option and how does it works with view

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

what is `with check` option and how does it works with view and if see good please be briefer introduction to view and what does it mean in concept of database and why we are using it as virtual table what is it use

Comment: Read [what questions to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as well as [what not to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) on this forum, then create a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and SO users will be glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You are guaranteeing that if the view fulfills the where condition on the view (such as where amount> 25 and it returns rows) it will continue doing so. If a user tries to delete to update the column (issue and update amount set amount -
 =12) that will remove the rows based on the condition SQL Server will not allow the update. In other words if you run the view and based on the where condition you get 10 rows back you will continue to get at least ten rows back.